Fresh forkable Ubuntu for complete user interface change
I'm looking for a Debian operating system that has no user interface, but that supports all necessary drawing libraries (OpenGL, perhaps Skia, and pixel plotting) and perhaps a lightweight HTML5 renderer that I can use to build my user interface.
It happens that existing distributions I found are already complete, so it is hard to modify them with the new user interface that I would to put over. For example, the start menu would be exactly as in Windows 8.1; the taskbar too, among many other things.
I've looked at Linux Mint, SparkyLinux... none that goes well that I can fork and easily modify. The Linux Mint Cinnamon repository does have an ui directory, but it already contains much logical code that I can easily break.
The operating system does need to support brightness adjustment too (that is, the correct graphics driver), wireless and sound drivers, among others.
Price: free
Processor: x86-64 or AMD64

Do you plan to develop a new desktop environment, like GNOME, KDE or Xfce? Or use one as a base and tweak it?

Windowsfx is a Linux distro with a Windows-like UI.

@A.L Hi, I wanted to develop a new one from scratch, except the several drivers and libraries (for example, Intel Graphics (brightness adjustment), Realtek drivers, touchpad) and have a base entry point for the desktop environment which I would implement in HTML5 (although I'm not a fan of HTML5, it's the only option right now).

Do you realize that developing a desktop environment is a huge project? GNOME, KDE or Xfce are made by teams of developers. Did you think about using one of them and expanding it through extensions or themes?
